# For a gold badge user, how to "propose" for closing a question as duplicate without completely closing it?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

In earlier times (with/without gold badge), when a user would hit "close" button for a "duplicate" question, it will automatically add a comment and mark a vote for the closing it.

With new "gold badge" rule, now it completely closes it. But I notice that sometimes, there is a opinion mismatch among the users which is expected. As a gold badge user, sometimes I feel that completely closing the Q is too strong an action. In such case, I can think of following ways:

- Flag for moderator attention -- *too slow*
- Put a comment manually -- *clumsy & unable to vote*
- Vote for close & ask for opinion via comment -- *not elegant*

Is there any other way which I am missing or already proposed?
The requirement is: **At times**, a gold badge user may still want to "propose" closing a Q as duplicate in the old school way.

<sub>It happens often. Here is the [latest example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37656427/what-other-forms-of-automatic-and-dynamic-storage-have-been-implemented-for-c#comment62791756_37656427).</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flagging in order to get a question closed is a bad thing to do. Probably all those flags will be declined with a message similar to *the community can handle this herself, just vote to close*.

With your gold badge comes extra responsibility, if you are not sure enough to close it, then don't. If you are 99% sure, vote to close and if there are other users with good reasons to reopen it, reopen it. You have the power to do that instantly, so there is not much harm done.

In all other cases, you can comment with a *Related / duplicate - [LINK]* kind of comment, and if that gets support, close the question.